# Animated component is undefined in react-native 0.10.1

Tags: animation, react-native, animated

I've created a new react-native project using `react-native init` command and then I tried to use Animated component to create a simple animation. The problem is that Animated is undefined when trying to call Animated.ValueXY() even if Animated component is added to React:

```
var {
  Animated,
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} = React;
```

Does anyone experienced the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You, also, need to include Image in your React vars. 
This is required for the vectors to work in animated.

Comment: I've added Image to React vars, but Animated is still undefined when calling Animated.ValueXY() inside componentDidMount function.